# With youtube-dl how to download all videos before a specific date more efficiently?

Tags: ubuntu, youtube-dl

I want to downloand all videos by a specific YouTube channel uploaded before a specific date with youtube-dl. Hence, I did `youtube-dl <url_to_youtube_channel> --datebefore <date>`. Before the videos are downloaded, youtube-dl first downloads the video webpages to check whether the upload date is before the specified date ("Downloading webpage").

The channel, however, has already uploaded approx. 1700 videos and thus downloading all webpages takes quite a bit of time. On top of that, I plan to run the above command multiple times for different dates. Thus, I wonder if there is a way to speed up the process?  Can youtube-dl maybe download a video's URL together with the creation date? In this case I could build a lookup table to extract the wanted URLs and then provide them directly to youtube-dl (the paramter `--datebefore` would be redundant then).

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). Copy the output information and paste as text, you can then format it as code.

Comment: Alright, should I edit my post and replace the image by text?

Comment: Jes, that's it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need that level of control, you might ask `youtube-dl` to first fetch and dump the information, to build your database. Later you can use `youtube-dl` to download just the videos you want.

This is an example, note that you can write your own `json` filter and output. For example:

```
$ youtube-dl --skip-download --print-json <URL-CHANNEL> | jq --join-output '.upload_date," ",.id," ",.title,"\n"'
DATE1 ID1 TITLE1
DATE2 ID2 TITLE2
...
```

The result is a text file, you can then process it as desired to filter the ids for `youtube-dl`'s actual download.